# How can I search in a list for elements that contain a substring in any of their property values?

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I am trying to search in a list of objects with a lot of properties. Looking for an elegant solution such as a lambda expression that can return a result based on a search string. This is my data source in simplified form. My actual `Customer` class has lots more properties:

```
public static class CustomerDataSource
{
    public static List<Customer> customerData
    {
        get
        {
            Customer customer1 = new Customer() { name = "Bert", address = "London" };
            Customer customer2 = new Customer() { name = "Jon", address = "New York" };
            List<Customer> listCustomers = new List<Customer>();
            listCustomers.Add(customer1);
            listCustomers.Add(customer2);
            return listCustomers;
        }
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

What kind of statement can return all the `Customer`s that contain the 'searchstring'. For example, if the search string is 'e' then it should return both `customer1` and `customer2` because both the `name` and `address` properties for `customer1` contain 'e'.

I could write something like the following, but then I would have to write a line of code for each property:

```
var list = CustomerDataSource.customerData.FindAll(x => x.address.Contains("e"));
var list2 = CustomerDataSource.customerData.FindAll(x => x.name.Contains("e"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Reflection to get all properties and combine it with LINQ:

```
var list = CustomerDataSource
           .customerData
           .Where(c => c.GetType()
                        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .Any(pi => pi.GetValue(c).ToString().Contains("York")))
           .ToList();
```

Above code returns only `customer2`.

But if you **do now want to search through all properties** during query, I would take an attributed approach - mark properties which you want to search through with your custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
sealed class SearchableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SearchableAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

and then modify your class accordingly, for example, to mark that only `name` should be used:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Searchable]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

and slightly modify above LINQ query:

```
var list = CustomerDataSource
           .customerData
           .Where(c => c.GetType()
                        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<SearchableAttribute>() != null)
                        .Any(pi => pi.GetValue(c).ToString().Contains("York")))
           .ToList();
```

***Note:*** As Sam said, aboce code assumes that you are interested in properties with type that have a suitable`.ToString()` implementation. So it would not work for example, in case of arrays. You must further modify this code to suits your needs. Here is an example of additional handling of arrays with suitable `.ToString()` methods:

```
var list = CustomerDataSource
           .customerData
           .Where(c => c.GetType()
           .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
           .Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<SearchableAttribute>() != null)
           .Any(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsArray 
                          ? (pi.GetValue(c) as IEnumerable<object>)
                               .Any(o => o.ToString().Contains("Paris"))
                          : pi.GetValue(c).ToString().Contains("Paris")))
```

Comment: Note that the above code assumes that public instance properties of any type are suitable. It also assumes that the `ToString` result of each property value should be searched. Make sure to customise this based on your specific requirements if you decide to take this approach.

Comment: What if one of the properties is a string array would this still work?