Using VB.net Framework 4.8 Can I search all properties of a class for a given value and if any of the properties match, return that value
I have say I have this class
Public Class People
     Public Property kids As List(Of String)
     Public Property first As String
     Public Property last As String
     Public Property age as Integer
End Class

Dim test As List(Of People) = PeopleList.Where(
 Function(p)
     Return p.first = sometextbox.text
 End Function
 ).ToList()

I know I can search individual properpties for a match like above.
But how can I search every property for a potential match. So say first doesn't match, but last does or the list of strings has a match to the text box. I know I could use Or...Or..Or.. to check each property, but my class is much larger and needs to be scalable. I.e: I don't want to have to come add OR lines to this for every new property in the future. Is this possible?
'I have tried something like the below but feel like it is heading towards a dead end
 Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(People).GetProperties()
 for each prop in Propepreties
    prop.getvalue()

Bottom line I want to filter a list of objects and return a list that contains all the objects where any of the properties of match a search criteria instead of only checking for one property.
Let me know your thoughts

Potential Answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914914/linq-search-several-properties-of-a-class-for-a-string-match-where-some-of-the-p
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182462/how-can-i-search-in-a-list-for-elements-that-contain-a-substring-in-any-of-their

One thing you can do is start declaring the results as IEnumerable instead of LIst, and then omit calling ToList(). This can dramatically improve performance in certain situations.

You won't be able to get rid of a mess of if/else or switch statements. While you can use reflection to get a collection of properties for the type and even read their values, you still need to manually check the type of the results to know to do things like descend into the kids list or get the string representation for the age.
If it were me, I would either add a bool IsMatch(string) method to the People type or bool IsMatch(People, string) in its own type, to get this more out of the way.
